# CTAS the output from COPY INTO

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

the `copy into` command returns [an output dataset](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#output).

[CTAS](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html#variant-syntax) can create a table from the results of a query.

combining the two, we would expect to get the list of loaded files into a new table.

```
CREATE TABLE MY_LOADED_FILES
AS
COPY INTO mytable
FROM @my_int_stage;
```

However, this returns:

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 3 at position 0 unexpected 'copy'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can put a `COPY INTO` statement inside another statement unfortunately. There is a way to do this however by using the [result_scan](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html) function to return the results of the previous query.

```
copy into test_database.public.test_table from @my_int_stage;

create temporary table test_database.public.test_table_results as (
  select * from table(result_scan(LAST_QUERY_ID()))
);
```

Of course you need to make sure the second query runs in the same session as the copy statement and also that it is run directly after the copy statement. Alternatively you can use the query id with the `result_scan`.

If you want to see which files were loaded why don't you just look at the [copy_history](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/copy_history.html) of the table?

Comment: result_scan will do the job! I want to know exactly which files were loaded by the process